# View ^M as newline in vim without persistent file conversion

Tags: file-formats

When editing a dos-format file from a codebase which is mainly used with Visual Studio in a Windows environment on my local Ubuntu machine with VIM, I get to see the ^M character instead of a newline.

According to the [VIM documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/digraph.html#digraph-table), this represents the carriage return character.

Further complicating the problem is that this only occurs in certain places in the file, so the newlines don't seem to have a *consistent* format.

By default, VIM recognizes the file as dos file-format, which I see by executing `:set ff?`.

My goal is to edit the file without breaking its platform conformity; I don't want to persistently *convert* the file, only because I'm editing in VIM. Hence, the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5843561/3646263) doesn't satisfy my problem. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22816221/3646263), doesn't either.

Given this requirement, can I get VIM to just *display* all ^M's as newlines via some syntax highlighting setting?

Note that ^M isn't composed out of plain characters. If you'd insert them manually in VIM, you'd have to insert Cntr-V before inserting each character.

Comment: You want to display them as newlines? Wouldn't you have double spacing on those lines then? Just hiding the `^M` won't do the trick?

Comment: @BLayer Why would I have double spacing? When I edit the file in Visual Studio on a Windows machine the `^M`s that occur inbetween lines in VIM are actually newlines, where the newlines give the correct view.

Comment: Because you already have linefeed (visually a newline). Now you're treating `^M` as newline, too. That's two newlines. Double spacing.

Comment: @BLayer We both misinterpreted the original issue. See the comments under my answer or my answer update for the actual situation.

Comment: Thanks @Rich ... not how I first read it at all.

Comment: @BLayer You consider s newline a *spacing*? I guess, a newline could be considered a spacing in the general sense.

Comment: @MusséRedi Double-spacing is a well known term indicating lines of text separated by empty lines (IOW newlines occuring in pairs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `^M` visible with `ff=dos`

If `set ff?` reports that the file is `dos` and you are seeing `^M` carriage return characters at the end of *any* lines, then your file already has broken, non-conforming line-endings.

e.g. if the file displays like this:

```
regular line
another regular line
line with an extra carriage return^M
third regular line
```

This means that the actual content of your file looks something like (broken into lines for clarity):

```
regular line^M^J
another regular line^M^J
line with an extra carriage return^M^M^J
third regular line^M^J
```

If this is the case, the appropriate cause of action is simply to delete the extra carriage return and to look into how the file came to have such odd line endings.

### `^M` visible with `ff=unix`

A more common scenario is that you have a file with mixed endings. This would result in a file where certain (dos-formatted) lines are displayed with a `^M` at the end of the line. If you were seeing a file like this, however, `:set ff?` would report `unix`, not `dos`.

This scenario can be fixed by adding carriage returns to lines which do not have them. I usually do this by yanking a carriage return from one of the lines that has one, and then using a `:global` command:

```
:g/[^\r]$/norm! $p
```

*N.B. As far as I am aware, you cannot easily perform the above fix with a `:substitute` command, because the carriage return in the replacement would be interpreted as a newline and instead a linefeed will be added.*

The carriage returns will still be visible after running command, but when you save and reopen, Vim will reinterpret the file as `dos` format.

An alternative fix is to remove *all* the carriage returns at the end of lines:

```
:%s/\r$/
```

This leaves you with a file with `unix` line endings, but it's easy to get Vim to convert these back into `dos` line endings:

```
:set fileformat=dos
```

### UPDATE: `^M` *instead* of newlines

It turns out that what the OP is seeing is something like this:

```
first line^Msecond line
third line
```

This means that some of the line-endings don't contain linefeeds at all, they are *just* a carriage return. (This is old "Classic" MacOS style for line-endings — `mac` in `'fileformats'`.)

Similarly to the situations described above, this is incorrect in a `dos` formatted file: the file *is* malformed, even if Visual Studio displays it in a way that *looks* correct.

This can be fixed with the following confusing `:substitute` command:

```
:%s/\r/\r/g
```

Of course, the command doesn't actually replace all carriage returns with carriage returns!

In the "search" part of the command the `\r` carriage return will only match the ones that are not being using in a CRLF line-ending pair. In the "replace" part, the carriage return is interpreted as a newline, splitting the lines correctly.

After making the edit, the file will now be correctly formatted with `dos` endings throughout, and so will display correctly both in Vim and Visual Studio.

### Viewing the actual contents with `xxd`

Vim comes with a hex editor that can be used to view (or edit) the byte-level contents of the file. If you're sceptical about what I've written above, you can double-check what actual line-endings are being used with the command:

```
:%!xxd
```

*N.B. **This will replace the contents of your file** with a hex-dump: when you are done, press `u` to undo the change and return to your file.*

The regular contents are displayed on the right, the corresponding hex-codes on the left. On the right-hand side, both carriage returns and linefeeds are displayed as dots, so a unix line-ending will be shown as `.` a dos line ending as `..` and a dos ending with an extra carriage return as `...`.

Comment: *If set ff? reports that the file is dos and you are seeing ^Mcarriage return characters at the end of any lines, then your file already has broken, non-conforming line-endings. e.g. if the file displays like this: (...)* It's worse. At the start of the file the `^M`s occur inbetween lines, where the line should suppose to be multiple lines; the `^M` should be interpreted as a newline.

Comment: @MusséRedi I've updated my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: On the update, your second example `first line ^Msecond line` precisely replicates the problem.

Comment: @MusséRedi Okay, then the actual content must look something like this: `first line ^Msecond line`, when it *should* look like this. `first line ^M^Jsecond line`. I'll update again to include a command to fix the issue.

Comment: If deleting the carriage return and inserting newlines in its place doesn't malform the view on a Windows machine using Visual Studio, I think I'll be fine. I'll try and reproduce it to tomorrow. :)

Comment: What would be the root cause of such a malformation? Visual Studio doesn't bother, only vim does.

Comment: @MusséRedi See newest update for the fix. I'm not sure how you ended up with "mac"-style line endings in a Visual Studio file. One possibility is that the lines were copy/pasted into Visual Studio from a mac-format source, but that seems unlikely (I have come across a `mac` format file once in my entire life). I'd argue that Vim's behaviour is better than Visual Studio's, as it allows you to see and fix the existing issue. Inconsistent line-endings are not really something you'd ever want to keep in a file, as they can also cause bigger issues elsewhere.